# Same string but different byte length

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm having some issues here trying to select some data.

I have a trigger that inserts in other table, but only if the string value doesn't exists on the other table , so I validate before insert by counting:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_puesto_x_empresa FROM p_table_1 
            WHERE PUE_EMP_ID = Z.PIN_CODEMP
            AND PUE_NOMBRE = v_puesto_nombre;
```

If the counter above is lower than 1 or equal to 0, then the process allow to insert data into the correspondent table.

As it turns out, is duplicating the data for some strange reason, so I checked the source.
I use a cursor that prepares the data I need to insert, and I noticed that for some strings, even though they are the same, it treats them as different strings.

```
select 
    UPPER(trim(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(nlssort(PIN_DESCRIPCION, 'nls_sort=binary_ci')))) PIN_DESCRIPCION,
    LENGTHB(UPPER(trim(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(nlssort(PIN_DESCRIPCION, 'nls_sort=binary_ci'))))) LEGTHB,
    LENGTH(UPPER(trim(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(nlssort(PIN_DESCRIPCION, 'nls_sort=binary_ci'))))) AS "NORMAL LENGTH",
    LENGTHC(UPPER(trim(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(nlssort(PIN_DESCRIPCION, 'nls_sort=binary_ci'))))) AS "LENGTH C",
    LENGTH2(UPPER(trim(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(nlssort(PIN_DESCRIPCION, 'nls_sort=binary_ci'))))) AS "LENGTH 2"
    FROM PES_PUESTOS_INTERNOS
     where pin_codemp = '8F90CF5D287E2419E0530200000AA716'
     group by PIN_DESCRIPCION
     order by PIN_DESCRIPCION asc
     ;
```

These are the results:
[image]

Results but in text :

```
PIN_DESCRIPCION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    LEGTHB NORMAL LENGTH   LENGTH C   LENGTH 2
---------- ------------- ---------- ----------
ADMINISTRADOR DE PROCESOS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        27            27         27         27

ADMINISTRADOR DE PROCESOS Y CALIDAD                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        36            36         36         36

AFORADOR                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
         9             9          9          9

AFORADOR                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        10            10         10         10

ASISTENTE ADMINISTRATIVO                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        25            25         25         25

ASISTENTE ADMINISTRATIVO                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        26            26         26         26
```

So my guess, is that for some reason, even though they are the same, somehow they are treated as different internally.

Note: this table loads user input data, so the results, although are meant to be the 'same word', may encounter some linguistic char difference, such as :

- user input 1: aforador
- user input 2: Aforador

For that reason, I applied the next piece of code, so I can process only the one word(string):

```
UPPER(trim(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(nlssort(PIN_DESCRIPCION, 'nls_sort=binary_ci'))))
```

So, if for example, I query the same data without that, I would get the following result:

```
    PIN_DESCRIPCION                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
administrador de procesos
administrador de procesos
Administrador de Procesos y Calidad
Aforador
aforador
aforador
```

I'll appreciate any help with this issue.

Thanks in advance.
My best regards.

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT DUMP(pin_descripcion) FROM <rest of your query.` for those rows?

Comment: Why do you store plain text data as `RAW`?

Comment: Putting a screenshot is a very bad idea for such character related question. Please post the result as formatted text, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 - and please provide the original value of `PIN_DESCRIPCION`

Comment: Hi @WernfriedDomscheit, I applyed the suggestions you made and edited the post. There I provided the text output and the origina value of PIN_DESCRIPTION.

Comment: Hi @MT0, these are the results: 
`Aforador  
Typ=1 Len=8: 65,102,111,114,97,100,111,114
aforador 
Typ=1 Len=9: 97,102,111,114,97,100,111,114,0 `

Comment: Well - then, as you can see, the lengths you reported aren't the lengths of the values you were interested in. The lengths are 8 and 9, not 9 and 10. Moreover, do you see the 0 at the end of the second DUMP? That is exactly what MT0 suspected. All the hocus-pocus you do with your strings ended up adding a `NUL` (character with ASCII code 0) to the end of the string. Which means that some hocus-pocus has already happened BEFORE storing the value in your table.

Comment: By the way - are you using the NLSSORT trick to get rid of accented letters? Or for some other, similar reason? That is a horrible hack. If you have an issue that you were "solving" with NLSSORT, perhaps that's worth its own question (which has probably been asked and answered already).

Comment: Hi @mathguy, yes, I'm using NLSSORT  to get rid of accented letters or some differences that may cause some trouble on a process I use in other parts of the application. So far, NLSSORT has been working great. The problems described here appeared only with data that was on the table before some development done to refactor some of the application data upload process. So understanding what you're saying, the error may come directly from the way the user uploaded the data, allowing to insert into the field without trimming the data into the `PIN_DESCRIPCION`  field beforehand.

Comment: Accented characters may cause trouble in at least two ways. One is that it may mess up comparisons (if the same word is written differently in two places - accented in one place, not accented in the other). This can be solved when you write comparisons - you can instruct the comparison to ignore accents. You shouldn't need any tricks for that. The other is if, for example, you must print the values, and the printer can only print ASCII. (Or things of that nature.) For that, you want to STORE the data after removing accents. That can be done in more natural ways than the NLSSORT trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This strings are not the same. The second one has another character that is not (obviously) being displayed.

If you do:

```sql
SELECT PIN_DESCRIPCION,
       DUMP(PIN_DESCRIPCION)
FROM   PES_PUESTOS_INTERNOS
WHERE pin_codemp = '8F90CF5D287E2419E0530200000AA716'
GROUP BY PIN_DESCRIPCION
ORDER BY PIN_DESCRIPCION asc;
```

Then you will see the binary values that comprise the data and should see that there is an extra trailing character. This could be:

- Whitespace (which you can remove with `RTRIM`);
- A zero-width character;
- A `NUL` (ASCII 0) character;
- Or something else that is not being displayed.

For example, if you have a function to create a string from bytes (passed as hexadecimal values):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION createString( hex VARCHAR2 ) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
IS
  value VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
  DBMS_STATS.CONVERT_RAW_VALUE( HEXTORAW( hex ), value );
  RETURN value;
END;
/
```

Then we can create the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value VARCHAR2(50) )
/

INSERT INTO table_name ( value )
SELECT 'AFORADOR' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AFORADOR' || createString( '00' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AFORADOR' || createString( '01' ) FROM DUAL
/
```

Then, if we use:

```sql
SELECT value,
       DUMP( value ) AS dump,
       LENGTH(TRIM(value)) AS length
FROM   table_name
```

This outputs:

> ```
> |     VALUE |                                   DUMP | LENGTH |
> |-----------|----------------------------------------|--------|
> |  AFORADOR |   Typ=1 Len=8: 65,70,79,82,65,68,79,82 |      8 |
> | AFORADOR | Typ=1 Len=9: 65,70,79,82,65,68,79,82,0 |      9 |
> | AFORADOR | Typ=1 Len=9: 65,70,79,82,65,68,79,82,1 |      9 |
> ```

*(Yes, the alignment of the table is messed up ... that's because of the unprintable characters in the string.)*

*sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2e0690/2/0)*

---

## Update:

From comments:

> > What is the output of `SELECT DUMP(pin_descripcion) FROM <rest of your query>` for those rows?
>
> These are the results:
>
> ```
> Aforador   Typ=1 Len=8: 65,102,111,114,97,100,111,114
> aforador  Typ=1 Len=9: 97,102,111,114,97,100,111,114,0
> ```

Look at the difference in the byte values.

- The first characters are 65 (or `A`) and 97 (or `a`); however, by using `UPPER`, you are masking that difference in your output. If you use `UPPER` in the `GROUP BY` then the difference in case will not matter.
- Additionally, the second one has an extra byte at the end with the value of 0 (ASCII `NUL`) so, regardless of case, they are different strings. This extra last character is not printable so you won't see the difference in the output (and is used as a string terminator so may have unexpected side-effects; for example, trying to display a `NUL` character in a db<>fiddle hangs the output) but it means that the strings are different so that `GROUP BY` will not aggregate them together.

You can do:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION createStringFromHex( hex VARCHAR2 ) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
IS
  value VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
  DBMS_STATS.CONVERT_RAW_VALUE( HEXTORAW( hex ), value );
  RETURN value;
END;
/
```

Then, to remove the `NUL` string terminators:

```sql
UPDATE PES_PUESTOS_INTERNOS
SET    PIN_DESCRIPCION = RTRIM( PIN_DESCRIPCION, createStringFromHex( '00' ) )
WHERE  SUBSTR( PIN_DESCRIPCION, -1 ) = createStringFromHex( '00' );
```

Then you should be able to do:

```sql
SELECT UPPER(PIN_DESCRIPCION) AS PIN_DESCRIPCION,
       LENGTH(UPPER(PIN_DESCRIPCION)) AS LENGTH
FROM   PES_PUESTOS_INTERNOS
--where pin_codemp = '8F90CF5D287E2419E0530200000AA716'
group by UPPER(PIN_DESCRIPCION)
order by UPPER(PIN_DESCRIPCION) asc;
```

and only see single rows.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7d611e20c7fc991f2a5f75c425a10698)*

Comment: The reason may be different from non-printing characters. For example, A is a graphical representation of the abstract concept of "letter A" of different alphabets (e.g. Latin capital letter A vs. Cyrillic capital letter A). Some character sets don't distinguish between these, but Unicode - for one - does. They are mapped to different code points, which are then mapped to different encodings - one is one-byte long in UTF8, while the other is three bytes long. They both *look* the same: `A`. In any case, **DUMP** will tell.

Comment: @mathguy That could be the case but the OP clearly shows that the second row has a length 1 greater than the first row even though both display as the same string.

Comment: Funny thing is, if both are plain ASCII, then the length should be 8, not 9 or 10. Which suggests that perhaps BOTH strings have some odd things in them (perhaps trailing).

Comment: And also - I just looked more closely at the OP's full message. He shows the "normal" length too, not just byte length. What I said applies to byte length, but it wouldn't explain the difference in "normal" length.

Comment: @mathguy That appears to be an artefact of the OP converting the string to a RAW and back [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2e0690/5). There appears to be an additional `NUL` (ASCII 0) character being appended to the string.

Comment: @mathguy I think major point is, we only see a **screenshot** of `UPPER(trim(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(nlssort(PIN_DESCRIPCION, 'nls_sort=binary_ci'))))` - but we would like to see the value of `PIN_DESCRIPCION`

Comment: Bingo! DUMP shows `NUL` at the end of one string. And, by the time the OP got the lengths of 9 and 10, there are probably one `NUL` in one string and **two** `NUL` in the other.

Comment: @MT0 Thank you very much for your help! By deleting the `NUL` ASCII char I could overcome the issue I had. I really appretiate it!